# Gerund, to-infinitive or bare infinitive?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

Which of the following three constructions is more common in everyday speech?

> 1. Nothing gives me greater pleasure than ***kissing*** my girlfriend.
> 2. Nothing gives me greater pleasure than ***to kiss*** my girlfriend.
> 3. Nothing gives me greater pleasure than ***kiss*** my girlfriend.

Comment: "Nothing gives me greater _er_  pleasure than...

Comment: None of these are correct as written, as @Cascabel is pointing out.

Comment: @Cascabel:You are right. l'll edit it.

Comment: Number 3 is ungrammatical. The other two are possible but are nuanced differently. The second one would more likely refer to a single kiss.

Comment: @WS2: Actually, l had doubts about No. 3. I wasn't sure of its use thinking that some people may use it In informal English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between 1 and 2, as WS2 noted earlier. However, I have been noticing that "to"+infinitive constructions have been increasingly occurring in instances where I would have expected a gerund. For example, with increasing frequency, I have heard speakers say, "Would you be interested to participate in this program?" where the meaning is closer to "Would you be interested in participating in this program?". It seems that the nuanced difference between "interested in" and "interested to," and similarly with the usages in 1 and 2, is in the process of being lost.